# Second monitor has low resolution

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

Just installed Ubuntu 15.10, and my second monitor does not use the correct resolution.  It defaults to `1024x768`, even though it should support `1920x1080`.  Previously, on Windows this was not a problem.  I had this same problem with this monitor on Arch Linux, and was able to correct it like this:

- The EDID had a bad checksum
- Set the `IgnoreEDIDChecksum` option on the Xorg configuration file
- In `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, under the `Device` section:

  ```
  Option "IgnoreEDIDChecksum" "DFP-4"
  ```

I'm not able to find that config option in Ubuntu (and I'm not sure if there is a better way to do it).  I've also tried adding a new mode through `xrandr`, but would get the following error:

```
xrandr --addmode DVI-D-0 1920x1080_60.00
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  41
  Current serial number in output stream:  42
```

Does anybody know how I can correct the problem, or how I can provide more information?  I'm using the proprietary NVIDIA driver (the open source driver would just display a black screen on that monitor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by generating an `xorg.conf` file through the NVIDIA settings application, then making the following entry in the `Device` section:

```
Option "IgnoreEDIDChecksum" "DFP-4"
```

Where `DFP-4` is the name of the monitor.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but my xorg.conf file has three different DEVICE sections. Which one did you add that line to?

Comment: @neuronet sorry for the delayed response. I'm not using the same setup anymore, so don't know for sure what the config looks like. If I remember correctly, I only had one DEVICE section. Either that, or I just put this in the first one that I found.