# What is the correct way to force a permanent monitor resolution change?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I am running 3 monitors off of a Geforce 970 with the following setup:

1. Mon1 (1024x768) connected to DVI port (native resolution 1920x1080)
2. Mon2 (1920x1080) connected to display port
3. Mon3 (1920x1080) connected to display port

What is the correct way to force the resolution on Mon1 to 1920x1080? Do I need to overwrite something in xorg.conf? or in the nvidia-settings-rc file?

`xrandr -q` output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4864 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected primary 1024x768+0+156 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00*+
   1360x768      59.96    59.80  
   1152x864      60.00  
   800x600       72.19    60.32    56.25  
   680x384       59.96    59.80  
   640x480       59.94  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       72.19  
   320x240       60.05  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected 1920x1080+2944+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00    50.08  
   720x480       59.94    60.05  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93  
   480x576       50.00  
   480x480       59.94  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected 1920x1080+1024+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94
```

xorg.conf (generated from within nvidia-settings):

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 361.42  (buildd@lgw01-18)  Tue Apr  5 14:33:28 UTC 2016

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: xconfig, VertRefresh source: xconfig
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DFP-0"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 55.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 970"
EndSection
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+156, DP-1: nvidia-auto-select +2944+0, DP-3: nvidia-auto-selec$
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: Are all three monitors exactly the same? If so, for testing purposes, swap mon 0 with one of the other monitors, and see if things change. Otherwise, I'd recommend looking for a firmware/software update for your video card. Cheers, Al

Comment: They are not exactly the same, but I did try swapping the port. No change in resolution.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if the resolution is due to some limitation in the DVI port? Did you check for a firmware/software update for the card yet? Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my specific case I had to change the resolution in in the `metamodes` option to `1920x1080` as well as add the line `Option "IgnoreEDIDChecksum" "DFP-0"` to the Screen section based on [this SO answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/689046/488579).